# Apple News on OSX

Tags: macos, ios, news.app

I enjoy using the Apple News application on my iPad and iPhone, does anyone know about any plans on bringing it to the web or OSX?

Comment: As Apple is notoriously tight-lipped about any updates, I suppose it will be available when it's available. I wouldn't hold my breath for a web version though, as Apple's priorities are Apps. You can see that especially clear in the development strategy of Safari: Chrome and Firefox, at this point even Internet Explorer, have more comprehensive support for modern web technologies than Safari does, Safari is far more energy-efficient though. For better or worse, Apple wants you to use Apps.

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to provide the info you want.  It took Apple 3 years to create an OS X version of the iBooks app, it you want an example.  Personally I find Apple News incredibly slow to update, all the items are so old I prefer other sources.

Comment: Although it is slow at times I find it more convenient than traversing though numerous news sites looking for interesting articles Do you recommend any News style applications or websites?

Comment: I’m from the future and I’m here to report that macOS 10.14 will include the News app in [supported regions](https://www.ctrl.blog//entry/apple-news-macos-worldwide).